# How to send a MultipartFile within a DTO in SpringBoot with React js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, dto, form-data

I'm trying to add an image file within a form with some other inputs,

This is what I followed in react(FrontEnd):

```
handleAddBtnClick=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile,this.state.selectedFile.name)

    let obj={
        name:name,
        price:price,
        image:data,
        quantity:quantity,
        shortDesc:shortDesc,
        longDesc:longDesc,
    }
    this.props.addCraftActions.addCraft(obj)
}
```

And sent as a post request

Spring boot Controller implementation is as bellow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCraftItem(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token, @RequestBody ItemDTO dto) throws Exception {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(craftItemService.addItem(dto));
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ItemDTO implements Serializable {
    private long craftId;

    private String ciName;

    private boolean availabilityStatus;

    private double ciPrice;

    private MultipartFile imgFile;

    private int itemQuantity;

    private String shortDescription;

    private String longDescription;
```

And I get the following exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

And I would like to know how I can this can be fixed. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: As the name suggests, multipart requests are essentially multi-part, meaning there is no single body. So `@RequestBody ` will not work. Instead use `@RequestParam` with a parameter name.

Comment: @KedarJoshi, after I do that;  @RequestParam(name="data") ItemDTO dto, I get this error "status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required ItemDTO parameter 'data' is not present"

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. Multipart requests are submitted similar to how a form request is submitted i.e. data is essentially *name - value pairs*. So `@RequestParam(name="data")` will only work if the submitted multipart form has a `data` parameter ?

Given structure of `ItemDTO` will not work for multipart requests as spring only maps request body or JSON value of a parameter to a POJO but not entire form data.

Comment: I don't know how react works but I assume `obj` properties will essentially become multipart request parameters. In that case something like `@RequestParam(name="price") String price` will give you value of the price parameter.

Comment: @KedarJoshi, thanks for the detailed explanation, it helped me understand better.